# Alguém sabe como criar este programa?

Tags: python, programação-imperativa

Escrever um programa em Python para criar um vetor `turmaA` com `N` valores reais e
um vetor `turmaB` com `K` valores reais, contendo as notas dos alunos das duas turmas, cujas notas deverão ser geradas de forma randômica com valores no intervalo de 0.0 a
10.0 (Ex.: 2.4, 8.7, 5.5, etc).

Pede-se:

- a) Calcular a média aritmética das notas da `turmaA` e a média aritmética das notas da
  `turmaB`;
- b) Calcular o número de aprovados em cada turma (nota igual ou superior a 5);
- c) Criar um vetor alunosAp com as notas dos alunos aprovados nas duas turmas. Imprimir os vetores `turmaA`, `turmaB` e alunosAp, bem como a média de cada turma e o respectivo número de aprovados.

```
    from random import choices 
    n = int(input("Digite o valor de N: ")) 
    lista = 1 
    quant = n 
    valores = range(0, 100) 
    turmaA = [choices(valores, k=quant) for _ in range(lista)] 
    print("As notas da turma A foram:",(turmaA))
```

Dica: Gerar valores inteiros de 0 a 100 e dividir por 10

Comment: O que você fez até o momento?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo somar os valores da lista randomizada com a função sum, para realizar a média

Comment: from random import choices
n = int(input("Digite o valor de N: "))
lista = 1
quant = n
valores = range(0, 100)

turmaA = [choices(valores, k=quant) for _ in range(lista)]
print("As notas da turma A foram:",(turmaA))

Comment: fiz de outra forma também

Comment: from random import randint
n = int(input("Digite o valor de N: "))
turma = [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(n)]
soma = sum(turma)
print(turma)
print(f'A soma das notas da turma é: {soma}')

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
import random

quantidade = int(input("Digite a quantidade de elementos: "))

turmaA = []
turmaB = []
aprovados = []

mediaTurmaA = 0.0
mediaTurmaB = 0.0
notaCorte = 5.0

quantidadeAprovadosA = 0
quantidadeAprovadosB = 0

# Preencher os vetores com as notas
for i in range(quantidade):
    turmaA.append(random.uniform(0.0, 10.0))
    turmaB.append(random.uniform(0.0, 10.0))
    
# Calcular média da turma A
for i in turmaA:
    mediaTurmaA += i

mediaTurmaA /= quantidade

# Calcular média da turma B    
for i in turmaB:
    mediaTurmaB += i
    
mediaTurmaB /= quantidade

for i in range(quantidade):
    if (turmaA[i] >= notaCorte):
        aprovados.append(turmaA[i])
        quantidadeAprovadosA += 1
        
    if (turmaB[i] >= notaCorte):
        aprovados.append(turmaB[i])
        quantidadeAprovadosB += 1

# Imprimir tudo
print("   TurmaA: ", turmaA)
print("    Média: ", mediaTurmaA)
print("Aprovados: ", quantidadeAprovadosA)
print("\n")
print("   TurmaB: ", turmaB)
print("    Média: ", mediaTurmaB)
print("Aprovados: ", quantidadeAprovadosB)
print("\n")
print("Turma Aprovada: ", aprovados)
```

Comment: Peguem leve nas críticas, eu não programo em Python. Fazer esse código foi um desafio e tanto :D .

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você deseja implementar um código em Python que seja capaz de montar duas lista - turmaA e turmaB - armazenando as notas de seus respectivos alunos, além de montar uma terceira lista - alunosAp - armazenando as notas dos alunos aprovados. Em seguida calcular a média aritmética das notas da turmaA e turmaB, calcular o número de aprovados em cada uma das turmas e exibir as listas e os resultados.

Em primeiro lugar você deve perceber que a quantidade de valores do vetor `turmaA` é **N** e a quantidade de valores do vetor `turmaB` é **K**. Isto nos diz que **nem sempres** estes valores serão iguais, existindo fortes possibilidades deles serem diferentes.

Uma das formas corretas para resolver esta questão é:

```
from random import uniform

n = int(input('Número de alunos da turma A: '))
k = int(input('Número de alunos da turma B: '))

turmaA = list()
turmaB = list()
alunosAp = list()

apro_A = 0
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    valor1 = round(uniform(0.0, 10.0), 1)
    turmaA.append(valor1)
    if valor1 >= 5.0:
        alunosAp.append(valor1)
        apro_A += 1

apro_B = 0
for j in range(1, k + 1):
    valor2 = round(uniform(0.0, 10.0), 1)
    turmaB.append(valor2)
    if valor2 >= 5.0:
        alunosAp.append(valor2)
        apro_B += 1

media_A = round(sum(turmaA) / len(turmaA), 1)
media_B = round(sum(turmaB) / len(turmaB), 1)

print(f'As notas da turma A são: {turmaA}')
print(f'As notas da turma B são: {turmaB}')
print(f'As notas dos alunos aprovados são: {alunosAp}')
print(f'A média da turma A é "{media_A}" e a quantidade de alunos aprovados é "{apro_A}".')
print(f'A média da turma B é "{media_B}" e a quantidade de alunos aprovados é "{apro_B}".')
```

Observe que a primeira coisa que foi feita neste código foi a importação da biblioteca `random`, bem como o método `uniform`. Em seguida foram implementados os `inputs`. O primeiro para capturar a quantidade de alunos da turmaA e o segundo, para capturar a quantidade de alunos da turmaB.

Prosseguindo, teremos o **primeiro bloco for**. Este, por sua vez, irá percorrer o **range(1, n + 1)**. E, para cada uma de suas interações, com a juda do método `uniform`, será gerado um valor real, sendo o mesmo arredondado para no máximo **1** casa decimal e, em seguida, adicionado a **turmaA**. Continuando o fluxo do código, o bloco **if** verificará se tal valor gerado na respectiva interação é maior ou igual a **5**. Caso positivo, o referido valor também será adicionado a **alunosAp** e a variável apro_A - variável que conta a quantidade de aprovados de turmaA - será incrementada em uma unidade.

Posteriormente, o fluxo do programa executa o **segundo bloco for**. Este, por sua vez, realizará um procedimento igual ao primeiro bloco for, sendo o mesmo redirecionado para **turmaB**.

Depois dessas operações o código irá calcular as médias aritméticas das duas turmas e, em seguida, exibirá os resultados.